# optimizing/ better way of coding a function and using its return value

Tags: c, optimization

I have some 20 to 30 functions, i have to call wsse_authenticate, in ever function for, and this wsse_authenticate function returns a value based on that value i send the fault message, Is there any way i can improve this code, so that i just call the function wsse_authenticate(soap) in every function and the switch case be replaced by some better code, i want to make it much efficient, Pls give me some inputs

```
wsse_ret = (wsse_authenticate(soap));

if(wsse_ret)
{
    switch(wsse_ret)
    {
        case 1: onvif_fault(soap,"ter:NoSecuritytoken","ter:Failed_wsse_Aunthentication");

        case 2: onvif_fault(soap,"ter:InvalidUserName","ter:FailedAunthentication");

        case 3: onvif_fault(soap,"ter:InvalidPassword","ter:FailedAunthentication");

    }
}
```

Comment: For starters you don't need the `if(wsse_ret)`, you already check `wsse_ret` after that.

Comment: Are you intending for all your case statements to fall through?

Comment: @Manu: "efficient" in which aspect? typing? runtime speed (if so, have you benchmarked your current solutions? what are the timings?)? etc etc. right now it is a bit unclear of what you want.

Comment: @Troy : I use this switch in every function along with wsse_security so i want to refine it

Comment: @Manu are they all the *same* content in every function, or only the relevant return codes (and are those codes *always* the same. I.e. `1` always means no-security token, etc..) ?

Comment: @WhozCraig: 1 always means no-securitytoken 2 always means InvalidUserName etc.. wsse_security performs the required functionality and returns the appropriate error value.

Comment: They yeah, I would setup a ranged error descriptions table, index it by error code, and default to something else (perhaps nothing) when outside that range. but as I said in my previously healthy answer, I wouldn't be surprised if a good optimizing C compiler did that for you with your switch anyway (assuming you put `break`s in there), so don't expect miracles in performance enhancements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the above code, I see that you are calling same function for all the cases expect for the "failure message" passed as an argument to function **onvif_fault**. And also there is no break after each case statement which would not give you result as expected.

**Explanation for using break statement:**
Suppose ret value is 1, then all the three cases would be executed since there is break statement at the end. Which means **onvif_fault** will be called three times with different parameters which is not expected.

**Solution for you question**
You can create a table using structures in c which actually has the list of the faults.
This was you can replace your Switch statements with only one line of code.

EX:
    typedef struct _fault_messages
    {
        char msg1[254];
        char msg2[254];
    }   fault_messages;

```
fault_messages msg_table[3] = {  
                    {"ter:NoSecuritytoken", "ter:Failed_wsse_Aunthentication"},  
                    {"ter:error1", "ter:fault1"},  
                    {"ter:error2", "ter:fault2"}
```

};

Now, your fault messages in the above table are mapped. You can optimize your code as mentioned below:

```
wsse_ret = (wsse_authenticate(soap));  

if(wsse_ret)  
{  
    onvif_fault(soap, msg_table[wsse_ret-1].msg1, msg_table[wsse_ret-1].msg2);  
}
```

Comment: @Manu : Did the above answer solved your problem or do you have any other concerns? Let me know...

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly - your main problem is that you don't want to repeat security checking code in each and every function from 30 function set :-)
If that is the case you can try to use such pattern:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int isUserPasswordValid(char * password) {
    return strcmp(password, "MyBigPassword") == 0;
}

#define callFunctionWithAuthentication(password, secPayload, execPayload) \
do {\
   if (!isUserPasswordValid(password)) {\
      secPayload\
   }\
   else {\
      execPayload\
   }\
} while(0);

int myTestFunction(int x) {
    return x;
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

   // bad password - executes only authentication
   callFunctionWithAuthentication(
               "randomPassword",
               printf("oops - bad password - can't continue\n");,
               int a = myTestFunction(10); printf("function returned %d\n",a);)

   // good password - executes authentication AND code after
   callFunctionWithAuthentication(
               "MyBigPassword",
               printf("oops - bad password - can't continue\n");,
               int a = myTestFunction(10); printf("function returned %d\n",a);)

   return 0;
}
```

Only drawback that you must replace the call of each 30 function into the call of `callFunctionWithAuthentication`. But this is one-time task. Further you must always call this macro instead of `plain` function.